# Why does the insert function and concatenation do this?

Tags: python, list, insert, concatenation

```
x = [4, 5, 6]
li = [1, 2, 3, 7]
li.insert(3,x)
x+=li
print(x)
```

The output is:

```
[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, [...], 7]
```

I'm new to python/coding and I don't know what these ellipses are but when I do other code it starts getting weird. Wasn't sure what to ask since I have no clue what's going on. Thank you!

Comment: *Wasn't sure what to ask since I have no clue what's going on*. Not sure what to answer since I have no clue what the problem is.

Comment: I think you don't want to insert the list in list. You want to insert items of the list in list.

Comment: You are inserting object `x` at position 3. Since `x` is a list, you are inserting a list inside a list.

Comment: Start with the basics, understand data structures types first. Then it will make sense.

Comment: @Vinny ty vinny i know what to look up now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're inserting a list inside your list, probably not what you want.

Then when doing this

```
x+=li
```

the representation of the list then shows an ellipsis because you're referencing the list from itself (`x` is referenced in `li` already)

To insert several items at once in a list in-place you could use slice assignment:

```
>>> x = [4, 5, 6]
>>> li = [1, 2, 3, 7]
>>> li[3:3] = x
>>> li
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: thank u ! so what I gather is that the insert function I used is actually referencing from 'x' itself and not simply taking its value ? thanks

Comment: because that's how python works: everything is reference, and lists are mutable. If you want to do this just use a copy of `x`: `x[:]` or `list(x)`